# Ruling on imposing islam on individuals under islamic state?

Tags: sharia, free-will, freedom-of-belief, freedom

If laws like apostasy exist then islam must also have given any law through which an individual has full right and absolute freedom to choose his religion and declare it infront of magistrate or authority after age of maturity and conscience even if he/she inherited islam. Or will islamic state impose his religion on individual. Sanctions may still be implemented I won't disagree with this. But it is unacceptable to force islam on someone.

Answer (score -3):

This aspect was discussed many time in this site. As I understand there are some sects among Muslims who believe it is ok to force Islam on people. These people claim it is ok to kill people if someone leave Islam but actually this goes against freedom of religion given in Quran 2:256,10:99. There is verse in which it states of a person, who repeatedly believe and disbelieve, if there is death penalty for leaving Islam, the person may not be there to believe again after his first disbelief.

> Indeed, those who have believed then disbelieved, then believed then
> disbelieved, and then increased in disbelief - never will Allāh
> forgive them, nor will He guide them to a way. [Quran 4:137](https://quran.com/an-nisa/137)

Those who support forcing religion on people do not have proof to prove their point whereas there are lot of verses in Quran that is against them.